# PL SQL Data Loading Issue

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a weird requirement to load the data from an unstructured table into a structured table. The unstructured table looks like below.

```
NUMBERID | MODEL| NAME | VALUE | CREATED_DT | LOADED_DT
1000     | BOE | AGT  | 300   | 02-AUG-2016| 02-AUG-2016
1001     | AIR | ACT  | 400   | 01-AUG-2016| 01-AUG-2016
1002     | EMB | ADT  | 500   | 02-AUG-2016| 01-AUG-2016
1004     | REL | GTR  | 140   | 01-AUG-2016| 01-AUG-2016
1005     | SIM | HJT  | 140   | 01-JUL-2016| 28-JUL-2016
```

This is how the table looks like and it has millions of records. Now I need to load the data into a different structured table. And here comes the real deal. This data is refreshed everyday through ETL job. I need to load the data which is two days old. So, I query on CREATED_DT using sysdate - 2 to get the data join with (MAX(NUMBERID) to MIN(NUMBERID)) to get all the records. Sometimes, new record will not be created in the table, rather the VALUE is just updated 4 days after and we need to update the new value in the new system.

So, how can I identify the value without comparing with the base table? 
Also, if the LOADED_DT will also be updated. As this table contains millions of records, how can I split the data into 10,000 records in each batch?

I am planning to do using MIN and MAX of NUMBERID. If I use this, I will be missing some records as there might be some records with less NUMBERID that needs to be inserted

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Nope.  Oracle doesn't do that work for you.  You should maintain your own information needed for your jobs to run successfully.

Comment: Sorry, the LOADED_DT will also be updated. As this table contains millions of records, how can I split the data into 10,000 records in each batch?
I am planning to do using MIN and MAX of NUMBERID. If I use this, I will be missing some records as there might be some records with less NUMBERID that needs to be inserted.

Comment: Just to update that I achieved this requirement by creating one structured Oracle table. I put all the data into that table and processed the records from the newly created table. This seemed a much easier option. Thanks guys for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update that I achieved this requirement by creating one structured Oracle table. I put all the data into that table and processed the records from the newly created table. This seemed a much easier option. Thanks guys for your help !